# Custom LineageOs Build for land Failed

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-source, lineageos

While trying to build `LineageOS-16` for land, stuck with following build errors.

```
camera.msm8937 (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm) missing libts_face_beautify_hal (SHARED_LIBRARIES android-arm)
```

Is it because of any missing vendor files?

I tried to extract the vendor blobs, but failed. Any suggestion please...

Comment: The Android build tooling is unable to find the module `libts_face_beautify_hal` which seems to be a custom vendor HAL from xiaomi. You `repo manifest` probably lacks the needed repository.